# GWT: Drag&Drop Event for TextField?

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, textfield

I wonder how it is possible to listen for the drop event for a `TextField`. I need to intercept that events in order to do value checks.

I wrote an extended `TextBox`, which fires `TextChangeEvents`. But when i drop a text into the text field, I don't get a call for the `onBrowserEvent(Event event)` method.

Any hint?

```
public class ExtendedTextBox extends TextBox {

    /**
     * Creates an empty extended text box.
     */
    public ExtendedTextBox() {
        super();

        // Catch the browser events.
        sinkEvents(Event.ONKEYUP);
        sinkEvents(Event.ONPASTE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        System.out.println(event.getTypeInt());

        switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONKEYUP:
            case Event.ONPASTE: {
            // Fire the event after the text box shows the new data.
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    fireEvent(new TextChangeEvent(ExtendedTextBox.this.getText()));
                }
            });
            break;
        }
        default:
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a given {@link TextChangeEventHandler} to the widget.
     * 
     * @param handler
     *            the handler
     * @return {@link HandlerRegistration} used to remove the handler
     */
    public HandlerRegistration addTextChangeEventHandler(TextChangeEventHandler handler) {
        return addHandler(handler, TextChangeEvent.TYPE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, the goal is to catch a drop event over a textbox, or catch any modification the textbox could have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I figured it out by myself today and it is quiet simple. I didn't notice, that there is already the `DropHandler`.

You can do this for example in the constructor:

```
addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
        if(!event.getDataTransfer().getData("text/plain").isEmpty()) {
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    fireEvent(new TextChangeEvent(ExtendedTextBox.this.getText()));
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

To prevent the default behaviour of the `TextField` just add `event.preventDefault();`. Now you can get the input by calling `event.getDataTransfer().getData("text/plain")` and do your input validation etc.

And as side effect the `onBrowserEvent(Event event)` method is called now by dropping something into the text field. But the type int is `-1`, so it's not really helpful at this place.

Answer (score 0):

A TextBox should fire a `ChangeEvent` (or `ValueChangeEvent` - don't know at the moment). So you could easily do something like this inside your constructor:

```
this.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler ...
```

If that's not enough, you could also listen to the `Focus` event.

Comment: Both the dom `ChangeEvent` and the logical `ValueChangeEvent` will only show up after blur, which may or may not be good enough...

Comment: But as far as I know there's no other possibility to recognize some kind of change inside a TextBox. As far as JavaScript is concerned it is just like *right click -> paste* or *ctrl+v*. ... HTML5 DropEvent shouldn't be possible, since there's no real *Element* to respond to. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Having not tested this yet, I'm not sure - it would not surprise me though to find that ONPASTE does not go off. The HTML5 dnd _seems_ as though it should work, since that only needs an element to listen to - it is given some drop data thing, which lets it deal with files from outside the browser, which also are not elements. One (ugly sounding) idea could be to listen for mouse up events, and check if the .getCurrentValue() of the field changed. My main reason in commenting was to clarify that while yes, those will fire, they won't fire right away.

Comment: The paste stuff is already working, the questionw as related to drag& drop e.g. marking a text and drag& drop it into the text field.